# Protractor- chrome headless in CentOS 7

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

We are trying to execute Protractor tests in CentOS 7 vm in headless mode using chromedriver.

**Versions**:

*Protractor- 5.4.0*

*Node - v6.14.3*

*cucumber-js - 4.2.1*

*Google Chrome version - Google Chrome 68.0.3440.84*

Webdriver-manager running and showing following information

```
[bpmuser@bg-bpm-qa-jbpm6 ~]$ ps -eaf | grep java
root      3692  3685  5 17:19 pts/0    00:00:01 java - 
Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.41 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.21.0 -jar /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -port 4444
```

**protractor.conf.js:**

```
var Cucumber = require("./node_modules/cucumber");
var { defineSupportCode } = require("./node_modules/cucumber");
var reporter = require('./node_modules/cucumber-html-reporter');
var report = require("./node_modules/cucumber-html-report");
var cucumberReportOptions = {
   source: './reports/results.json',
   dest: './reports/results',
   name: "report_detailed.html",
   title: "CDocs Automation Report",
};
var cucumberReporteroptions = {
    theme: 'Bootstrap',
    jsonFile: './reports/results.json',
    output: './reports/results/report.html',
    screenshotsDirectory: './reports/screenshots/',
    storeScreenshots: true,
    reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
    launchReport: false,
    metadata: {
        "App Version":"Angular 2.0",
        "Test Environment": "QA",
        "Browser": "Chrome",
        "Platform": process.platform,
        //"Parallel": "Scenarios",
        "Scenarios" : "TestCases",
        "Executed": "Local"
    }
};

exports.config = {
  //directConnect: true,
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
  getPageTimeout: 60000,
  allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
  framework: "custom",
  // path relative to the current config file
   frameworkPath: require.resolve('./node_modules/protractor-cucumber- framework'),
//restartBrowserBetweenSuites: true,
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
    args: [ 'headless' ]
 },
acceptSslCerts: true,
},

// Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
  specs: ['./features/ChangeView.feature',
 ],

//baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  onPrepare: function () {
  browser.baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";      
 },

 onComplete: () => {
  reporter.generate(cucumberReporteroptions); //invoke cucumber-html-reporter
  report
    .create(cucumberReportOptions)
    .then(function() {
      //invoke cucumber-html-report
      // creating two reports(optional) here, cucumber-html-report gives 
    directory already exists as cucumber-html-reporter already creates the html dir!
      // suggestion- use either one of the reports based on your needs
      console.log("cucumber_report.html created successfully!");
    })

    },
  cucumberOpts: {
   format: ['json:reports/results.json', 'pretty'],
   require: ['./features/step_definitions/content_step_definitions.js'],
   tags: true,
   profile: false,
   'no-source': true
   }
   };
```

However, running Protractor still does not work:

```
[bpmuser@bg-bpm-qa-jbpm6 bin]$ pwd
/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin
[bpmuser@bg-bpm-qa-jbpm6 bin]$ ./protractor /home/bpmuser/docs/CDocsAutomation/protractor.conf.js
[18:10:33] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[18:10:33] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
```

Its not progressing after this step. Not sure where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your config

```
 capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',

    chromeOptions: {
        args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600" ]
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Still same issue.

Comment: Are you able to run normally in browser?

Comment: Same setup is working in Windows 10 with browser and headless. But not working in CentOS 7

Comment: Do you run the test as root, it will not start and fail your tests.  Create a another account and try running your test. You will get this issue if you are running chrome as root.

Comment: Now i am getting "E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally"   How to start Xvfb as per above Capabilities ?